# css blur works only if i remove unprefixed

Tags: css

I'm trying to do a cross browser blur in effect but my CSS seems to works only if i remove the unprefixed version

I'm testing it on chrome

```
.blurin {
    -moz-animation: blurin 3s;
    -webkit-animation: blurin 3s;    
    animation: blurin 3s; /* remove this to work */
}

@-moz-keyframes blurin { 
 0%     { -moz-filter: blur(0px); }
 100%   { -moz-filter: blur(10px); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blurin {
 0%     { -webkit-filter: blur(0px); }
 100%   { -webkit-filter: blur(10px); }
}

/* remove this to work */
@keyframes blurin { 
 0%     { filter: blur(0px); }
 100%   { filter: blur(10px); }
}
```

Comment: Cannot replicate - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rLpOjO It's smoother in FF than it is in Chrome but it still works.

Comment: I'm using an .svg file could it be that?

Comment: That seems likely but you'd have to demo it....but the prefixing shouldn't be an in issue.

Comment: can i just embed a .svg that i find googling?

Comment: No need - https://jsfiddle.net/bn4duqg8/

Comment: Looks like this is a bug - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109224

Comment: not sure what is the difference but here doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/3e1646do/ and here it does http://codepen.io/al404/pen/LkZpjZ

Comment: Now that is weird.

Comment: i got why codeine works, even if this is pretty odd. in source the iframe has in style tag a modified version of original css and @keyframes blurin as -webkit-filter

Comment: OK....it works in my Codepen (and your fork) because I had an **autoprefixer** turned on..phew figured that one out. http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/QEajRN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replicated the issue which seems to affect SVG images only. [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bn4duqg8/1/)

```css
.blurin {
  -moz-animation: blurin 3s;
  -webkit-animation: blurin 3s;
  animation: blurin 3s ease infinite;
  /* remove this to work */
}
@-moz-keyframes blurin {
  0% {
    -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-filter: blur(10px);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blurin {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  }
}
/* remove this to work 
@keyframes blurin { 
 0%     { filter: blur(0px); }
 100%   { filter: blur(10px); }
}
```

```html
<img class="blurin" src="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120330024139/logopedia/images/d/d7/Google_Chrome_logo_2011.svg" alt="">
```

Since `filter` property is not supported for SVG objects I suspect that the `filter` property is overriding the `-webkit-filter` one and so is failing for these image types/

This seems to be a bug in Chrome/Blink - See this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109224

Comment: seems a bug, not sure if codepen way to manage the problem is correct http://codepen.io/al404/pen/LkZpjZ work because iframe embedded css has -webkit-filter instead of filter in @keyframes blurin

Comment: As I mentioned, my initial Codepen (and your fork of it) had an *autoprefixer* JS working in the background. If you turn it off, the Codepen doesn't work....as expected.